# Get Image Url From RSS MEDIUM FEED

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic2, rss, medium-editor

I am trying to display each image from each post from medium's rss feed, without using JQuery, but only javascript or angular, in HTML.
Is it possible to get the image from the RSS feed? I am receiving the title, the date it was created at and the link.
I am working with Ionic2.

```
entries: any    = null;
image: any      = null;
```

In my constructor:

```
        Feed.load('https://medium.com/feed/@jaymelone', (err, rss) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            this.entries    = rss.items;
            this.image = this.entries.find('img').eq(0).attr('src');
        }
        console.log("RSS function - entries:", this.entries);
        console.log("RSS function - image: ", this.image);
    });
```

In my HTML

```
    <div class="post" *ngFor="let entry of entries">
      <div class="inner">
        <img class="img" [src]="entry.image">
        <p class="title">{{entry.title}}</p>
     </div>
   </div>
```

But I receive:

```
<img class="img" src="undefined">
```

And:

```
TypeError: Array.prototype.find callback must be a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your console.log call is outputting the image name correctly, everything looks in order except you need to use ng-src instead of src, like this:

```
<img class="img" ng-src="{{entry.image}}">
```

Comment: My bad, I forgot the ng-src. But the console log doesn't ouput the src as it should, i'm having some errors, so that's why I think this  this.image = this.entries.find('img').eq(0).attr('src'); might not be the best way.

Comment: Also, ng-src doesn't work and was thinking of using [src]="entry.image" but I receive <img class="img" src="undefined">

Answer (score 0):

Try `entry.image.url`.

Example:

```
<img class="img" [src]="entry.image.url">
```